# A client has just dropped like 20,000 lines of ObjC (iPhone) source code on me, the previous coder has split, where to start?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

20,000 lines of spaghetti code (iPhone ObjC) was just dropped in my lap. QUESTION: where to begin, is there a tool to just profile it all?  It's a mess, not even sure where to start. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: if you are a real developer you should know no know can reply you without even knowing what you need to do

Comment: Are there profiling tools that people recommend when faced with something like this? Sure I know I can start at square 1. But maybe there is a "magic bullet". What I need to do is run a utility that spits out all the class names, methods, links, variable names, etc. Not sure why people are down voting this, it's not such a crazy question. [IMHO] :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something called Unified Markup Language (UML). This is a critically overlooked part of the development process and is used to layout "class names, methods, links, etc".

Luckily for you, your problem has been faced by many a programmer in the past and there are a few different Magic Bullet solutions available. Since I've never worked backwards from code to UML (normally you build the UML first) I had to do a quick search to find some solutions:

This one looks promising: [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)

or this one: [AutoGraf](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/AutoGraf.shtml)

And I'm sure with a few minutes on Google you can find everything you need if these don't work out for you; now that you're aware of UML.

Comment: OmniGraffle will create a UML diagram for you if you drop an XCode project on it... It's not pretty, but it 'kinda sorta if you look at it from the right angle and don't expect too much' works.